# Eliminar ceros al final de cada registro SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Muy buenas tardes, tengo los siguientes registros:

```
1201045000000
1201045310000
1201000140000
1201045340000
1201045453400
1200000545455
```

Deseo realizar un script que me de como resultado lo siguiente:

```
1201045
120104531
120100014
120104534
12010454534
1200000545455
```

Como se ve, se retiran los ceros que se encuentran al final de la cadena, tener en cuenta:

1. La cantidad de ceros al final varia.
2. Hay registros que tienen ceros en medio de la cadena, ejem: 12**00000**545455, 1201**000**140000

No he podido usar `substring` por las distintas cantidades de ceros al final y por que cuenta con ceros en medio de la cadena.

Espero puedan ayudarme. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo combinando las funciones `REVERSE` y el `CONVERT` en *SQL SERVER*

Ejemplos:

como cadena

```
 select REVERSE(convert(varchar(20),convert(BIGINT ,REVERSE('1201045000000'))))
```

como valor numerico

```
select REVERSE(convert(varchar(20),convert(BIGINT ,REVERSE(1201045310000))))
```

Comment: Una solución muy ingeniosa.

Comment: Como recomendación cambiar el INT por BIGINT ya que si lo pruebas con el dato 1200000545455 veras que te marcara un error.

Comment: buena observación @EdgarVazquez , ya la he actualizado

Comment: +1 por el ingenio para resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pude con el problema segun lo indicado, mil gracias.

Comment: Por favor, siempre que vayan a usar varchar, nvarchar, char o nchar siempre especifiquen la longitud de los mismos para evitar problemas de truncado silencioso. Es una buena práctica aunque aquí no sea un problema.

Comment: @LuisCazares Gracias por la observación, tu comentario fomenta a publicar respuestas siempre procurando la calidad del código anexado

Comment: Para sacarse el sombrero el ingenio de esta respuesta.

Answer (score 7):

Para eliminar los ceros a la derecha puedes emplear `trim()` de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT TRIM('0' FROM '1201045000000')
```

esto devuelve:

```
1201045
```

puedes ver como funciona la función en el siguiente enlace:

<kbd>[Demostración](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/59586)</kbd>

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: El único "problema" con esta solución es que requiere SQL Server 2017 y muchas empresas no están actualizadas.

Comment: ya me imaginaba @LuisCazares gracias por la acotación.

Comment: Excelente, lamentablemente no contamos con Sql Server 2017, muchas gracias

Answer (score 6):

Esta es otra solución más que no utiliza dos REVERSE puesto que es una función costosa en SQL Server. Añadí un espacio a uno de los valores para verificar que no afectara.

```
SELECT *, 
       LEFT(Cadena, LEN(Cadena) - PATINDEX( '%[^0]%', LTRIM(REVERSE(Cadena))) + 1)
FROM (VALUES('1201045000000'),
            ('1201045310000' ),
            ('1201000140000 ' ),
            ('1201045340000' ),
            ('1201045453400' ),
            ('1200000545455'))x(Cadena);
```

Agrego una prueba de rendimiento de las soluciones propuestas. La solución de `the-breaker` no está porque no tengo acceso a la versión 2017 para esta prueba.

```
--Crear datos de prueba aleatorios
SELECT TOP (1000000)
        CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) AS varchar(25)) Cadena
INTO #test
FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b;

DECLARE @Dummy varchar(25), --Variable para no tener que mostrar resultados (eso toma tiempo)
        @Tiempo datetime2 = SYSDATETIME(); --Variable para medir el tiempo

--Medición base sin funciones
SELECT @Dummy = Cadena
FROM #test;

SELECT DATEDIFF(MS, @Tiempo, SYSDATETIME());
SET @Tiempo = SYSDATETIME();

--Solución Luis Cazares
SELECT @Dummy =  LEFT(Cadena, LEN(Cadena) - PATINDEX( '%[^0]%', LTRIM(REVERSE(Cadena))) + 1)
FROM #test;

SELECT DATEDIFF(MS, @Tiempo, SYSDATETIME());
SET @Tiempo = SYSDATETIME();

--Solución Juan Carlos Hdz
SELECT @Dummy =  REVERSE(convert(varchar,convert(BIGINT ,REVERSE(Cadena))))
FROM #test;

SELECT DATEDIFF(MS, @Tiempo, SYSDATETIME());
SET @Tiempo = SYSDATETIME();

--Solución Johan Donado B.
SELECT @Dummy = dbo.quitar_ceros(Cadena)
FROM #test;

SELECT DATEDIFF(MS, @Tiempo, SYSDATETIME());
SET @Tiempo = SYSDATETIME();
GO
DROP TABLE #test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero crear esta función:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION quitar_ceros 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @numero VARCHAR(13)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(13)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @pos INT

    SET @pos = LEN(@numero)

    WHILE SUBSTRING(@numero, @pos, 1) = '0'
    BEGIN
        SET @pos = @pos - 1
    END

    RETURN SUBSTRING(@numero, 1, @pos)

END
GO
```

Luego la llamas en tu consulta:

```
SELECT dbo.quitar_ceros('1201045000000')
```

Te devuelve 1201045

Comment: Esta opción es al menos 10 veces más lenta que cualquiera de las otras presentadas.

Comment: Me imagino que sí será algo más lenta, pero no creo que 10 veces.  De hecho es imperceptible.  Yo uso ese tipo de funciones en mi trabajo diario y no se nota una lentitud significativa.

Comment: Revisa la adición que hice a mi respuesta con la prueba de rendimiento. Una función escalar por si misma hace más lenta la consulta. Pero, además evita que puedas tener procesamiento paralelo en tus consultas. Por si fuera poco, también recibirán un impacto adicional si se usa el Profiler.

Comment: Creo que esa discusión es para otro post.  La idea era que se le dieran diferentes alternativas al compañero que hizo la pregunta.

Comment: Pues a mí me parece que la idea es dar las alternativas y además las herramientas adecuadas para seleccionar la mejor.